# Overload operator++ on pointers

Tags: c++, class, pointers, operator-overloading

I have a class:

```
class Name {
public:
    int key;
    Name* next;
}
```

How can I write the `operator++` so that when `p` is `"Node* p"` if I write `"p++"` it will do `"p = p->next"` ?

Anticipated thanks,
Marron.

Comment: You can't overload `operator++` for primitive types. Pointers are primitive types.

Comment: You mix up "Node" and "Name" in your question.

Answer (score 6):

You can't, nor should you, because it's counter-intuitive.

Thing about having an array of such objects:

```
Name names[42];
Name* p = names;
p++;
```

`p` should now point to the second element in the array (i.e. `names[1]`), not to whatever `names[0]` holds.

If an object holds a pointer to the next object, then at best applying `++` to the object itself (not a pointer) should give you the next object.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is simple: you can't! Overloading always involves, at least, one user-defined type. Pointers are always considered built-in types, even if they point to user-defined types. You will need to create a suitable class to create an iterator.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Luchian Grigore said, the iterators in the standard library address exactly what you are trying to accomplish. If you want to provide an iterator for your class, adding `operator++` to the iterator would make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it the following way.

```
class Students
{
private:
   class Name {
   public:
       int key;
       Name* next;
   };
   Name *head = {};
   Name *current = {};
public:
   Students & operator ++()
   {
      if ( current ) current = current->next;
      return *this;
   }
   // other class members
};
```

Comment: Hello ! Thanks for this reply. This looks really cool, but I am not able to understand this code... Can you please explain it to me and how I should use it ? (I'm pretty new to operators) Anticipated thanks, Marron.

Comment: @user3603899 Class Students (you may name it as you want) is simply a wrapper for your list Name. You can create an object of type Student and apply operator ++ to this object that to get a name from the list.